# Warning message: In if (CID2$XPM != 0) { : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, sas

Hello I am writing a program that takes x and y coordinates and calculates the azimuth of a force.  I have written the following code.

```
if(CID2$XPM != 0){
  CID2$APVECAZI <- atan(CID2$YPM/CID2$XPM)*180/3.14159
}else if(CID2$XPM < 0){
  CID2$APVECAZI <- CID2$APVECAZI + 180
}else if(CID2$XPM > 0 & CID2$YPM < 0){
  CID2$APVECAZI <- CID2$APVECAZI + 360
}else if(CID2$XPM == 0 & CID2$YPM > 0){
  CID2$ACVECAZI <- CID2$AVECAZI <- 90
}else if(CID2$XPM == 0 & CID2$YPM < 0){
  CID2$APVECAZI <- CID2$AVEDCAZI270
}
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
Warning message:
In if (CID2$XPM != 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Would anyone know how to correct this.  I have SAS Code that this is based off that works without a problem, but in R I am stuck.

SAS CODE is:

```
IF  XPM NE  0   THEN    APVECAZI=ATAN(YPM/XPM)*180/3.14159;
IF  XPM LT  0   THEN    APVECAZI=APVECAZI+180;
IF  XPM GT  0   AND YPM LT  0   THEN    APVECAZI=APVECAZI+360;
IF  XPM=0   AND YPM GT  0   THEN    APVECAZI=90;
IF  XPM=0   AND YPM LT  0   THEN    APVECAZI=270;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just a note that your SAS code should also be IF/ELSEIF for faster processing as well. Your R code is if/ifelse.

Comment: Yes I agree.  We are suppressing SAS at my company and I have been takes at rewriting the code that they have used for close to 10 years.  A daunting task for myself as I'm not strong in either language.  Thank you for the advise though. I do appreciate it.

Comment: I hate when companies do that. I'm surprised the conversion isn't going to cost them more in long run without appropriate resources dedicated to a transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` statement in R in a nested fashion.  This ends with a `NA` for last assignment.

```
CID2$APVECAZI <- ifelse(CID2$XPM !=0, atan(CID2$YPM/CID2$XPM)*180/3.14159, 
                         ifelse(CID2$XPM <0, CID2$APVECAZI+180,
                                ifelse(CID2$XPM > 0 & CID2$YMP < 0, CID2$APVECAZI+360, 
                                      ifelse(CID2$XPM == 0 & CID2$YPM > 0, 90, 
                                            ifelse(CID2$XPM == 0 & CID2$YPM < 0, 270, NA))))) 

CID2
  XPM YPM APVECAZI
1   0   2       NA
2   0   2       NA
3   0  45       NA
4  50  90 60.94545
5  60 275 77.69205
6 275   0  0.00000
```